# Python HTML parse, getting tag name with its value

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup at Python.
Is there a way to get property name with its value like:

**name=title value=This is title**

**name=link value=.../style.css**

soup.html.head=

```
<meta content="all" name="audience"/>
<meta content="2006-2013 webrazzi.com." name="copyright"/>
<title> This is title</title>
<link href=".../style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.text` or `.string` attribute to get text content of the element.

Use `.get('attrname')` or `['attrname']` to get attribute value.

```
html = '''
<head>
    <meta content="all" name="audience"/>
    <meta content="2006-2013 webrazzi.com." name="copyright"/>
    <title> This is title</title>
    <link href=".../style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print('name={} value={}'.format('title', soup.title.text))  # <----
print('name={} value={}'.format('link', soup.link['href'])) # <----
```

output:

```
name=title value= This is title
name=link value=.../style.css
```

**UPDATE** according to the OP's comment:

```
def get_text(el): return el.text
def get_href(el): return el['href']

# map tag names to functions (what to retrieve from the tag)
what_todo = {
    'title': get_text,
    'link': get_href,
}
for el in soup.select('head *'): # To retrieve all children inside `head`
    f = what_todo.get(el.name)
    if not f: # skip non-title, non-link tags.
        continue
    print('name={} value={}'.format(el.name, f(el)))
```

output: same as above

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working. But i'm looking for another way, using a loop to get all value at one time.like `while(){print property,value}`

Comment: @ridvanzoro, Then you need to define what tags should retrieve text content, what tags should retrieve what attributes first.

Comment: I'm getting error at meta tag. How can i parse meta tag? `for el in self.soup.select('head *'): if el.name=='meta': ...?`

Comment: @ridvanzoro, Do you mean `content` attribute of `meta` tag? Did you define it in the mapping?

Comment: I did exactly the same thing. But i get error:`return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'content'`

Comment: @ridvanzoro, It seems like, in your real html, there's no `content` attribute for some tags. Replacing `el['content']` with `el.get('content', 'fallback-default-value')` will give you default value instead of raising `KeyError`. Try it.

Comment: @ridvanzoro, If you have another question, please post a separated question. Doing so, you have more chance to be answered.